# calling a timer when a button is pushed

Tags: timers

I'm trying to call a function to keep an LED on for a certain amount of time. The function is called when the button is pushed but the LED stays on. I used the same code in the void loop before moving it into a function and it worked.

```
const int ledPin2 = 2;
const int buttonPin7 = 7;
const unsigned long onTime = 1000;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;


// 
void timer(){
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
    digitalWrite(ledPin2, HIGH);

    if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= onTime){
        digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW);
        previousMillis = millis();
    }
}


void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(ledPin2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(buttonPin7, INPUT);
}

void loop(){
    int buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin7);
    if (buttonState == HIGH) timer();
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a monostable multivbrator?

Answer (score 2):

When your code:

```
if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= onTime){
    digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW);
    previousMillis = millis();
}
```

was in the loop, it was executed multiple times, so when `if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= onTime)` eventually became true, it would set ledPin2 LOW again.
Now that you moved it to the `timer` funtion, it only gets executed once (and `if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= onTime)` never gets a chance to become true).

You need to introduce a loop in the `timer` function. It also looks like you have your `currentMillis` / `previousMillis` messed up. I think you are looking for something like this:

```
void timer(){

    unsigned long previousMillis = millis();
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
    digitalWrite(ledPin2, HIGH);

    while((currentMillis - previousMillis) < onTime) {
        // wait for a bit
        sleep(10);
        // update currentMillis
        currentMillis = millis();
    }

    digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW);
}
```

Comment: This did work really well. I do have an issue though. I setup another button and LED and used the same code while changing the variable names. If the second button was pressed when the first LED was on the second LED wouldn't turn on. If the first LED was off then the second would turn on if the second button was pressed.

Comment: Ask a new question, and post your code...

Answer (score 1):

Your code says

```
if (buttonState == HIGH) timer();
```

So... what will it do if `buttonstate` is `LOW`? Sorry, but the answer is "nothing". You don't have any code to tell it what to do when the button is in the opposite state.

What you should do is check the button, and if it's pressed (whether that's `HIGH` or `LOW` depends on your circuit), then light the LED and start the timer (assign to `previousMillis`).

Then, *regardless of the state of the button*, check to see if `currentMillis - previousMillis >= onTime`. If it is, then turn off the LED.

Comment: I had the LED write low in the timer function. The button was just calling the function and when the time elapsed it would tell the ledPin to write LOW.